# Windows Black Animations on Second Monitor

Tags: windows, windows-10, multiple-monitors, black-screen-of-death, animation

I've recently added a second monitor to my Windows 10 PC, and since day one many desktop animations and previews are black. To list some:

- Window switch to maximize/windowed mode animation
- Window previews when hovering over apps on the task bar<
- In the Win+Tab menu the wallpaper and all window previews are black
- Same when dragging a window against a screen edge for the selection of the second window

On the desktop switch animation (Ctrl+Win+Left/Right) the incoming desktop is black until the end of the animation, and the initial desktop is way too bright during the animation

Not all animations are broken though, some do work:

- Dragging windows around
- Resizing windows but not to fullscreen
- Dragging and holding windows against the screen border (until you release the mouse)
- Windows menu animations
- Right-click menu animations

All animations still work perfectly fine on the main monitor.

The second monitor has is from a different brand than the first monitor and has a different refresh rate, but has the same resolution (1440p). I don't think it has something to do with that though, is seems to be a software bug.

Here are some videos from the broken animations:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cXwcVxzqfvDSPDkgBtMBX1_28VRIP6rv/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B2tOZbYxhKsBlFNvCf-hbBLbGrXGX_Yo/view?usp=sharing (I don't mean the screen being too bright after the animation, that's obviously because of the recording, but that at the begin of the animation the initial desktop is way too bright)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem. It seems to have to do something with enabled HDR on the main monitor. Disabling HDR in the Windows settings is a workaround for the black animations on the non-HDR second monitor. Also making the non-HDR display the main monitor is a workaround (then all animations are as expected in HDR and SDR mode). Tested myself on Windows 10, 10.0.19044 Build 19044. I assume you also have a HDR main screen, and a non-HDR secondary screen? So far I couldn't find too other many reports on this issue online; and no true solutions.

Comment: I don't see a clearly formulated question in the main post. Besides, I think my post is helpful, because it mentions 2 methods to circumvent this Windows bug. It is true that these aren't real fixes for the underlying bug, but for some people (who can live with disabling HDR or making the other monitor the main one) it will solve the issue. Thus deleting my answer wouldn't be helpful to those people.

Comment: I do have HDR on the main monitor and not on the second one, indeed. And I think this answer absolutely has its place here, it does, in some ways, solve the problem. @DarkDiamond Honestly, what answer did you expect? It clearly a Windows bug, so you ain’t really solve it. I have seen much worse answers. Before you complain, give me a better solution, seriously.